# Loading persisted CrossValidatorModel throws "Param numTrees does not exist" Error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I am creating a RandomForestClassifier using Spark 2.0 for solving a multiclass classification problem. I am able to train the model successfully and save the trained model using the model.save() method to an S3 bucket. However while loading this model using the load() I am getting the following error.

`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Param numTrees does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$$anonfun$getParam$2.apply(params.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$$anonfun$getParam$2.apply(params.scala:609)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$class.getParam(params.scala:608)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.getParam(Pipeline.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$$anonfun$getAndSetParams$1.apply(ReadWrite.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$$anonfun$getAndSetParams$1.apply(ReadWrite.scala:429)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.getAndSetParams(ReadWrite.scala:429)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel$RandomForestClassificationModelReader.load(RandomForestClassifier.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel$RandomForestClassificationModelReader.load(RandomForestClassifier.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.loadParamsInstance(ReadWrite.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$$anonfun$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:267)
o.a.p.h.InternalParquetRecordReader         at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$$anonfun$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:265)
:   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
 block read in memory in 4226 ms. row count = 52598
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
2017-05-04 21:53:08.140 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.load(Pipeline.scala:265)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:335)
--- at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.loadParamsInstance(ReadWrite.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel$CrossValidatorModelReader.load(CrossValidator.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel$CrossValidatorModelReader.load(CrossValidator.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable$class.load(ReadWrite.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel$.load(CrossValidator.scala:240)
:   at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel.load(CrossValidator.scala)
```

`

Below is the code snippet that I use to train and save the model

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler();
assembler.setInputCols(inputColumnNames);
assembler.setOutputCol("Inputs_Indexed");


//split 70:30 training and test data
val Array(trainingData, testData) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

//train using RandomForest Model
val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
        .setLabelCol("Facing_Indexed")
        .setFeaturesCol("Inputs_Indexed")
        .setNumTrees(500);

val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
                .setInputCol("prediction")
                .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
                .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels);

val stageList = new ArrayList[PipelineStage];
stageList.addAll(categoricalInputModels);
stageList.add(labelIndexer);
stageList.add(assembler);
stageList.add(rf);
stageList.add(labelConverter);

val stages= new Array[PipelineStage](stageList.size);

//convert stages list to array
stageList.toArray(stages);

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(rf.maxDepth, Array(3, 5, 8)).build()

val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
  .setLabelCol("Facing_Indexed")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
  .setMetricName("accuracy")

val cv = new CrossValidator().setEstimator(pipeline).setEvaluator(evaluator).setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)

val model = cv.fit(trainingData)

val predictions = model.transform(testData);

predictions.select("predictedLabel", "Facing", "Inputs_Indexed").show(5);

val accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
  println("Test Error = " + (1.0 - accuracy))

model.save("s3n://xyz_path/au.model")
```

After the trained model is saved I use the CrossValidatorModel.load("s3n://xyz_path/au.model") to load the model in a separate Java program which throws the above mentioned error. In my S3 bucket I can see the serialized model being saved. I am not sure where it is going wrong. Any help with respect to this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. The AWS EMR cluster was running Spark 2.1.0 using which I was training and saving my model to the S3 bucket. However in my Java Program I was pointing to 2.0.0 version of Spark MLLib. I found that there was a breaking change related to the "numTrees" Param in RandomForestClassifierModel reported in the 2.0 to 2.1 migration guide here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#from-20-to-21

So, finally I updated the Spark MLLib maven dependency in my Java Project to point to version 2.1.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It then complained about an additional missing class

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/commons/compiler/UncheckedCompileException
```

It got fixed when I added the commons-compiler dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And thats how finally my persisted model was successfully loaded !